# Difficulty creating very small select statements for Angular Material web app for phone

Tags: angular-material

I have been having trouble creating a web app for a phone using Angular and Material Design components. In order for my web app to work well on a phone, it needs to have small buttons and small select statements. Unfortunately, it looks like the framework is adding a style statement for the select element. That style statement is specifying the width of the element and the width it is specifying is way too big. How can I specify small select statements?

Below are the key parts of the two input files: app.component.html and app.component.css. There is a third section that shows the code that is generated by Angular2 as I see it in Chrome's developer tools. The key part of that code is the style statement (style="width: 139.325px;"). If I change the width using the develop tools then I can get the button size I want. I just don't know how to get the size i want using the CSS file.

```js
----  Resulting Ang2 Code -----

<md-select _ngcontent-c0="" placeholder="Number of players" role="listbox" ng-reflect-model="4" ng-reflect-placeholder="Number of players" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid mat-select" tabindex="0" aria-label="Number of players" aria-required="false" aria-disabled="false" aria-invalid="false" aria-owns="md-option-0 md-option-1 md-option-2 md-option-3 md-option-4 md-option-5 md-option-6 md-option-7 md-option-8"><div cdk-overlay-origin="" class="mat-select-trigger"><span class="mat-select-placeholder mat-floating-placeholder" style="width: 139.325px;">Number of players </span><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "[object Object]"
}--><span class="mat-select-value"><span class="mat-select-value-text">4</span> </span><span class="mat-select-arrow"></span> <span class="mat-select-underline"></span></div><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-origin": "[object Object]",
  "ng-reflect-positions": "[object Object],[object Object",
  "ng-reflect-offset-x": 0,
  "ng-reflect-offset-y": 0,
  "ng-reflect-min-width": "152.3249969482422",
  "ng-reflect-backdrop-class": "cdk-overlay-transparent-backdr",
  "ng-reflect-has-backdrop": "",
  "ng-reflect-open": false
}--></md-select>
```

```css
---- My attempt to override the css for the select statement in app.component.css -----

md-select{
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 1px;
    min-width: 12px;
}
md-option{
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 1px;
    min-width: 12px;
}
```

```html
---- My app.component.html ---------

<md-select placeholder="Number of players" [(ngModel)]="numPlayers" (ngModelChange)="onChangeNumPlayers()" >
   <md-option *ngFor="let mynum of numberOfPlayersList" [value]="mynum.value">{{ mynum.name }}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

My friend Sergiu from Romania helped me out with this. The framework creates elements that encapsulate the md-select and md-option elements. You cannot set the styles for elements outside of md-select and md-option using app.component.css. In order to control those elements you need to add them to the base styles.css file. These classes were sufficient to shrink the select statement for me.

```
.mat-select,
.mat-select-trigger,
.mat-select-placeholder,
.cdk-overlay-pane,
.mat-select-panel,
.mat-select-content
{
    min-width: 40px !important;
    width: 40px !important;
}
.mat-option {
    padding: 0 2px!important;
}
```